# XOR combinations

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, combinations, xor

Can someone give me idea on how to approach the following problem?

## Task

We are given

- an interval [0,**n**]
- a number of steps **k**
- a starting number **p**

with the constraints 0 ≤ n,k,p ≤ 1000000000

In every step we randomly select a number q from the interval [0,n] and replace p with p XOR q. We have to calculate the expected value of p after k steps, modulo 1000000007.

## Two Examples With Given Solutions

In the case of **`n=3 k=1 p=0`** the expected value is 500000005 because
((0+1+2+3)%1000000007)/(4%1000000007) = (6*inverseModulo(4))%1000000007 = 500000005

In the case of **`n=4 k=2 p=1`** the expected value is 320000005.

## My Problem

I guess that solution has to do something with the bit representation of the numbers because every number has at most 32 bits, but after 5 hours of thinking I still have no idea how to solve this.

Can someone please give hints on what should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m trying to follow your instructions.  Where is the step where you are supposed to do `p XOR q`?

Comment: @ManLaw Well k is number of times we are supposed to do p xor q. In first testcase k is 1 , p is 0 and n is 3 so we only once replace p with p xor q where q is random number from interval [0,3]

Comment: @harold sorry, it should be n,k and p, I've fixed it

Comment: I can’t edit your question.  For clarity change "First line of input is the number of test cases.  For each test case, we input n, k, and p, respectively."

Comment: @ManLaw Ok, it's fixed.

Comment: I removed irrelevant details from your question, like the number of test cases and the input format. If you really really really want to go back to the original version you can roll back by clicking on "*edited ... ago*" and then on "*rollback*" , however I wouldn't recommend it, after all we want to focus on the actual problem and not on parsing some list of numbers.

Comment: It also could help if you could add a link to the source of the problem. I've seen this kind of input format a lot on StackOverflow and think it's from a website with programming tasks.

Comment: This looks like a math problem instead of a programming problem.

Comment: Is your XOR the bitwise XOR ? Because in the `n=3 k=1 p=0` case, I fail to see how `p = 0 XOR q = q` with `0<=q<=3` could ever give 500000005. Also could you explain why `((0+1+2+3)%1000000007)/(4%1000000007) == 500000005` ? With the usual definitions of "divide" and "modulo" operations, [this is equal to 1.5](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tXTHLT82Indf5lyr)